# Is the following code thread-safe in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I have code similar to the following in a Python module:

```
_x = None

def set_x():
 global _x
 _x = # some value (will always be the same)

def worker():
 if _x is None:
  set_x()
```

Can threads created in a client of this module safely call worker()?

X is used in a read-only mode elsewhere in the module; once set it is never changed.

Yes, I realize that x could be encapsulated in a class and the threads could create their own instances of that class on the stack and thus obtain thread-safety, but assume for the purposes of this question that a class-based implementation is not feasible or desirable (e.g., the module represents a Singleton where the cost of setting x is relatively high and we want to set it as infrequently as is practical).

Comment: You are aware that `x` is only overwritten locally in `set_x` and will stay `None` in the global scope?

Comment: Yes! Good catch. Thank you Klaus. For the purposes of this question, assume that each function that references x has the necessary global statement at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a global variable in `set_x`:

```
x = None

def set_x():
    global x
    x = "foo"

def worker():
    if not x:
        set_x()
```

There is a race condition between `if not x` and actually setting x. So multiple threads may assign a value to `x`. That's mostly harmless for immutable objects but problematic for mutable objects like lists where reassignment loses values in the existing `x`. And by "mostly", even objects whose values compare may have different id's, so `==` may work but `is` may fail:

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> b = "bar"
>>> c = a + b
>>> d = a + b
>>> c == d
True
>>> c is d
False
```

And of course code paths that don't play the `set_x` game may find that `x` changes from `None` to your expected value while they execute.

Especially because `x` is expensive to calculate, a good approach is to hide it behind a getter. Now everyone has to play the same game and only one of the threads will actually do the work.

```
_x = None
_x_lock = threading.Lock()

def get_x():
    global _x
    if _x is None:
        with _x_lock:
            if _x is None:
                _x = "foobar"
    return _x
```

Comment: Yes, x is global -- please see the updated example. And yes, the race condition between setting x and testing its value was my point of concern. This solution looks pretty robust. Assuming x is a string (immutable in Python IIRC) would we still be in "mostly/always? harmless" territory with the original code?

Comment: Mostly harmless. If its a hard-coded string then it has the same id even if set multiple times. But if its constructed, even identical strings have different ids. So, code can't use "is" (but they shouldn't anyway). `None` always has the same id, so `x is None` is fine but usually its a bad idea.

Comment: Strictly speaking, are two tests required for x is None, one prior to obtaining the lock, and the other after?

Comment: You need to do a test inside the lock to make sure testing plus changing can't be interrupted by another thread. The outer `if` is just for performance. Its quicker and once `x` has been set there is no need to grab the lock.

Comment: Thank you! (and thanks for the numerous other Python tips embedded in your answer; e.g., use of the leading underscore, x is None vs. not x, etc.)